# Stop Retry in WSO2 ESB Endpoint

Tags: wso2-esb

I have used below endpoint property and want it to stop retry hit but still it is retrying. I want only one hit to endpoint whether it is success or failure.

```
<endpoint name="DecisionGatewayProxy_EPR">
    <address uri="http://XXXX:8280/soap/XXXX">
        <timeout>
            <duration>20000</duration>
            <responseAction>fault</responseAction>
        </timeout>
            <markForSuspension>
            <errorCodes>101504, 101505</errorCodes>
            <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
            <retryDelay>1</retryDelay>
        </markForSuspension>
        <suspendOnFailure>
            <errorCodes>101500, 101501, 101506, 101507, 101508</errorCodes>
            <initialDuration>20000</initialDuration>
            <progressionFactor>0.0</progressionFactor>
        </suspendOnFailure>
    </address>
</endpoint>
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK the default behavior is sending a single request. And if it fails ESB marks it as timed out.So IMO it won't try again automatically upon time out. But if you need to mark the endpoint as SUSPENDED you can make `<retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>` 
value into 1. So this will mark the endpoint SUSPENDED after single endpoint failure.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is this sure according to you that if we set a retry policy, esb will automatically resend the message to the endpoint (and the message / sequence will be replayed) ? It's not yet 100% clear how it's working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that it is possible to do it in WSO2 ESB. As a suggestion, make sure to send a response from the server regardless of success or failure (at least send 202 ACCEPTED) then it will not retry to send the same message.

Comment: Thanks for posting comment here, really appreciate it. Could you please let me know with any example that how to send 202 status so that it will not retry it?

Comment: you can write http server to return 202 when nothing is changed.